# What Stack Exchange network can I ask a question about business cards?

Tags: support

What Stack Exchange network can I ask a question about business cards?

Answer (score 3):

```
What is the ideal width for very high-quality professional business cards?
```

This is not on topic anywhere on Stack Exchange. You'll need to do research yourself on this one. It doesn't really fit any of our sites and is very broad. It also differs per each person.

Comment: My specific question is something to the extent of "what is the ideal width for very high-quality professional business cards?"

Comment: @techaddict You will likely not be able to do that on any site then. You will need to research it yourself.

Comment: @techaddict thats the problem - it IS broad. No one has a specific answer, everyone will have a different one. It isn't constructive.

Comment: @techaddict *Very* high quality business cards can be entirely custom and not necessarily made from paper. The web is full of examples, like Kevin Mitnick's business cards.

Answer (score 3):

For business cards, there are ["standard" dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_card#Dimensions) that vary by country.

Comment: Well that was... easy to find.

Comment: @SimonSheehan Don't believe your teachers' propaganda. Wikipedia is a an excellent source (if used correctly). :P

Comment: I've learned the tricks to using it ;)

Comment: I have no need to learn about standard dimensions. Business cards are 3.5"x2". That is the standard size. My question has nothing to do with your answer.

Comment: The question you posed to Simon was "What is the ideal width ... for business cards". I am not following what you are saying. You seem to already know the answer to your question.

Comment: @techaddict Really wide question and _off-topic_ on _SuperUser_ ... BTW if you want allow people to store your business card __it has to fit__ into the larger number of business card holder... because on the contrary it will be cut or trashed... `:)` ps> Non standard 85x50mm...